# Regex to obtain everything till the second to last occurrence

Tags: regex, perl

For example if I have `rrr.abc.tsy.html`

I just want `rrr.abc`

How can I use a regular expression to extract everything prior to the *second to last* occurrence of `.` (the period character)?

Comment: Do you mean to take the last two parts separated by a period?

Comment: "Till the second to last occurrance" of what? Letters followed by a dot? More examples would help.

Comment: For example: rrr.abc.txy.html I would like to obtain everything before .txy.html

Comment: I think you need to show more code. *"I have rrr.abc.tsy.html"* tells us very little, Are those fields in a Perl array or in a single Perl string? If you can publish the code that created those values then we would be able to help much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the string itself to strip the latter portion:

```perl
my $str = 'rrr.abc.tsy.html';
$str =~ s/^(.+)(\.[^.]+){2}$/\1/;
```

Or you can leave the string alone and simply grab the matching portion in another variable:

```perl
$str =~ /^(.+)(\.[^.]+){2}$/;
my $match = $1;
```

Explanation of regular expression:

```
^               Match at beginning of string
(               Start capturing group 1
    .+              1 or more of any character (except newline)
)               End capturing group 1
(               Start capturing group 2
    \.              A single literal period
    [^.]+           1 or more of any character except period or newline
)               End capturing group 2
{2}             Match exactly 2 of the stuff in capturing group 2
$               Match at end of string
```

The second capturing group and its 2 multipler `(\.[^.]+){2}` matches the last two suffixes.

The first group, being "greedy," matches everything it can before then.

Comment: `s/^(.+)(\.[^.]+){2}$/\1/` can be simplified to `s/(?:\.[^.]+){2}\z//`. And that `+` should probably be `*`.

Comment: `$str =~ /^(.+)(\.[^.]+){2}$/; my $match = $1;` is buggy. `$match` contains something unknown if the match fails. `my ($match) = $str =~ /^(.+)(\.[^.]+){2}$/;` avoids that problems. Better yet, `my ($match) = $str =~ /^(.*)(\.[^.]*){2}\z/;`

Comment: @ikegami The `+` is there instead of `*` on purpose to avoid matching `'.foo.bar'` and returning `''`. In any case I'm not going to refine this further unless the OP updates the question, due to current hold for unclear...

Answer (score 1):

> *I would like to obtain everything before .txy.htm*

```
my $s = 'rrr.abc.txy.html';
my ($wanted) = $s =~ /^(.*?)\.txy\.html/;
say $wanted;  # rrr.abc
```

If instead you want to remove any trailing `.txy.htm`,

```
my $s = 'rrr.abc.txy.html';
$s =~ s/\.txy\.html\z//;
say $s;  # rrr.abc
```

If instead you want everything before the second last `.`,

```
my $s = 'rrr.abc.txy.html';
my ($wanted) = $s =~ /^(.*)\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\z/;
say $wanted;  # rrr.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a little creative with `substr` and `rindex` you can get a much faster solution.

```
my $str = 'rrr.abc.tsy.html';
my $one = substr($str, 0, rindex($str, '.')); # $one = 'rrr.abc.tsy'
my $two = substr($one, 0, rindex($one, '.')); # $two = 'rrr.abc'
```

Here's where we get creative. Rather than create an interim variable, you can wrap the `substr` inside another `substr` to get the result instantly (and which my Benchmarks show to be a good 300% faster than using regex or split).

```
my $wanted = substr($str, 0, rindex(substr($str, 0, rindex($str, '.')), '.'));
# $wanted = 'rrr.abc'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
^(.+)[.][^.]*[.][^.]*$
```

Explanation:
It will match
`^` from the beginning
`(.+)` a group of any length of any characters
`[.]` that are followed by a dot,
`[^.]*` then optionally by some non-dot characters,
`[.]`then by another dot
`[^.]*` and optionally by other non-dot characters
`$` until the end

The result will be captured in variable `$1`.

The question is unfortunately not clear enough to understand whether the groups of non-dot characers have to be optional or not.